# Spring Boot send logs to ElasticSearch

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, logging, logback, elk

I have a Spring Boot application. I want to send the logs to ElasticSearch so that later I can use Kibana to make some dashboards and statistics. Here is my `logback.xml` file

```xml
<configuration>
<appender name="ELASTICSEARCH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
    <destination>localhost:9200</destination>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <customFields>{"index":"sdk-logs"}</customFields>
        <pattern>%magenta(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}) %highlight([%thread]) %-5level [userId: %X{orgid}] %cyan(%logger{36}) -
            %blue(%msg%n)
        </pattern>
        <index>sdk-logs</index>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="ELASTICSEARCH"/>
</root>
</configuration>
```

As far as I understand this should automatically create an index with the name sdk-logs on ElasticSearch and send logs to this index. ElasticSearch and Kibara are dockerized and running on ports `5601` and `9200`. To start the application I needed to add this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
    <version>7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This whole setup is not working. The app is not creating the index on ElasticSearch. I'm trying to confirm that with http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v

```java
health status index                           uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   .geoip_databases                B_c2UakQQLeqPbh_h6zqqQ   1   0         42           38     39.3mb         39.3mb
green  open   .kibana_7.15.0_001              TT0Zy7fcTw23_8jMII4XJg   1   0        102           20      2.3mb          2.3mb
green  open   .apm-custom-link                Nh-LWRvOQB2wuabBUlDwgg   1   0          0            0       208b           208b
green  open   .kibana-event-log-7.15.0-000001 TNnCY1x6Q6mtCCs5seau9A   1   0          2            0     11.9kb         11.9kb
green  open   .apm-agent-configuration        tbmgbDmjSvWjE2qdRGaQpQ   1   0          0            0       208b           208b
green  open   .async-search                   ca5hu_yXQcyNjqCqC3JoOA   1   0          0            2      3.4kb          3.4kb
green  open   .kibana_task_manager_7.15.0_001 NaHmMJZTQ6aQYekhgKO3hw   1   0         15         2580    668.7kb        668.7kb
green  open   .tasks                          ppCejuqLQO6hW6RDyVeOvg   1   0          2            0      7.8kb          7.8kb
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but the app is logging this

> WARN in
> net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[ELASTICSEARCH]
> -Log destination localhost/:9200: Waiting 29993ms before attempting reconnection.

Answer (score 0):

`logstash-logback-encoder` is used to send log to logstash, not directly to ElasticSearch. You need to deploy a logstash instance. This doc will help you to deploy a logstash instance, and how it works with ElasticSearch
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html